# How to run a text file using a batch file?

Tags: unix, batch-file, text-files

I have a text file"FTPXM.txt" which has code like this

```
open unix.server.com 

user namepwd

cd /home/20150715/crediting/
find -name XMP*17357*|tar -rf /home/tar/my_tar.tar
bye
```

How should I run this code?

I used a bat file 'xml.bat' which looks like

```
C:
C:\Users\manoj\Documents\
ftp -v -n -s:C:\Users\manoj\Documents\FtpXM.txt
```

The batch is running but I am not able to see any tar file in that destination.

Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

I think the `.bat` file is wrong. I am not sure but I guess so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` to change to a directory (add `/d` to change the drive too):

```
cd /d C:\Users\manoj\Documents\
ftp -v -n -s:FtpXM.txt
```